# d-q-frame-currents. What and where are they in PMSM?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, homework, synchronous-motor

I am doing a course in power electronics. We discuss a lot about Iq and Id, when we are talking about a three phase system and electric motors.
I like to visualize things to make them more understandable.

Question: Regarding PMSM (Permanent-Magnetic Synchronous Machine):
What is the Iq/Id-current? where is it in the machine?

Answer (score 1):

The Iq and Id currents for a PMSM are similar to Iq and Id for a salient-pole wound field synchronous machine (WFSM). Iq and Id are phasor components of the armature current. The Iq component is in phase with the generated armature voltage and produces a magnetic flux that is centered on the space between the permanent-magnet field poles. Id produces a magnetic flux that is centered on the permanent magnet poles.

Answer (score 1):

Id and Iq don't actually exist in the machine.  They are a transformation (Park transform) of the stator currents to the rotor reference frame; imagine a fictitious set of windings that rotate with the rotor: The D (direct) winding is aligned with the rotor field, and the Q (quadrature) winding is perpendicular; they carry the currents Id and Iq, respectively. If you were sitting on the rotor, you would not be able to tell the difference between the actual 3-phase stator winding and the fictitious D-Q winding arrangement. However, analysis is simplified because in the rotor reference frame, inductances don't vary with motor speed and position.